# ActiveJobs: Cómo serializar un xlsx para pasarlo como argumento a perform_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recibo un documento xlsx desde el cliente y necesito que ese archivo xlsx sea leído en el método perform de Active Jobs para procesar la data, pero cuando el documento lo mando a al perform me da un error de ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: Roo::Excelx). Cómo logro hacer esto?

Estoy utilizando ruby 2.7.1 y rails 5.1

```
 def upload_file
    file = params[:file]
    if file.respond_to?(:read)
      document = ''
      case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when '.xls'
        document = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, extension: :xls)
      when '.xlsx'
        document = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, extension: :xlsx)
      when '.csv'
        document = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, extension: :csv)
      else
        raise
      end
      debugger
      document.sheets.each do |actual_sheet|
        if document.sheet(actual_sheet).row(1)[0] != 'NAME' ||
            document.sheet(actual_sheet).row(1)[1] != 'DESCRIPTION' ||
            document.sheet(actual_sheet).row(1)[2] != 'EXPIRE DATE' ||
            document.sheet(actual_sheet).row(1)[3] != 'QUANTITY' ||
            document.sheet(actual_sheet).row(1)[4] != 'BRAND' ||
            document.sheet(actual_sheet).row(1)[5] != 'MODEL'
          then raise
        end
      end
      CreateStockJob.perform_later(document)
      render status: :ok
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Método perform:

```
def perform(document)
    debugger
    document.sheets.each do |actual_sheet|
      (2..document.sheet(actual_sheet).last_row).each do |row_number|
        row = document.sheet(actual_sheet).row(row_number)
        product = Stock.where(name: row[0], expire_date: row[2], brand: row[4], model: row[5],
                              enterprise_id: params[:enterprise_id])
        if product.empty?
          stck = Stock.create(
            name: row[0],
            description: row[1],
            expire_date: row[2],
            is_perishable: !row[2].nil?,
            quantity: row[3],
            brand: row[4],
            model: row[5],
            enterprise_id: params[:enterprise_id]
          )
          render raise unless stck.save
        else
          product[0].quantity = row[3]
          product[0].save
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debe ser posible serializar las instancias de `Roo::Excelx`, lo cual está bien. No se cual sea el `queue_adapter` que tengas configurado, pero suponiendo que fuese Sidekiq, no tiene sentido mandar un archivo que puede pesar... no se, 1GB? o lo que sea y guardarlo en Redis, o sea en la ram, para despues ser procesado.
La idea es que siempre trates de mandar tus parámetros [lo más pequeño posible](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices), en tu caso debería ser la ruta del TempFile asociado a la subida, o sea:

```rb
CreateStockJob.perform_later(file.path)
```

Y luego abrirlo por el lado del método `perform`